# PHP preg_match_all to find multiple base64 images

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, preg-match-all

I have a JSON string that may contain one or multiple base64 images.

Here is an example of the JSON string and the REGEX which only find the first occurance.

```
<?php 
    preg_match_all('/(data:\s*\S*\/(\w*);base64,[^\"]+)/', $content, $result);
```

Here is my content,

```
<?php 

    $content = '{"textArea":"one","signature":"data:image\/png;base64,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",'.
    '"textArea1":"","signature1":"data:image\/png;base64,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",'.
    '"textArea2":"three","signature2":"data:image\/png;base64,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",'.
    '"textArea3":"fourrrr4444"}';
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The regex syntax gets tricky here, because you have the literal text `image\/png` in your input.  The backslash must be escaped *six* times here, four for a literal backslash, and two for an escape for the forward slash (which is also the delimiter used in the call to `preg_match_all`).  Consider this script:

```php
$content = '{"textArea":"one","signature":"data:image\/png;base64,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",'.
'"textArea1":"","signature1":"data:image\/png;base64,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",'.
'"textArea2":"three","signature2":"data:image\/png;base64,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",'.
'"textArea3":"fourrrr4444"}';
preg_match_all("/\"data:image\\\\\\/png;base64,([^\"]+)/", $content, $matches);
print_r($matches[1]);
```

This prints:

```
Array
(
    [0] => iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAABFUAAA...
    [1] => iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAABFUAAA...
    [2] => iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAABFUAAA...
)
```

Answer (score 2):

This is much easier if you first [`json_decode`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode) the text; then you can simply check each value in the decoded result to see if it begins with a valid `data:image` and if so, add it to your output:

```php
$data = json_decode($content, true);
$images = array();
foreach ($data as $value) {
    if (preg_match('#^data:image.*?base64,#', $value)) {
        $images[] = $value;
    }
}
print_r($images);
```

Output:

```php
Array
(
    [0] => data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSU...
    [1] => data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSU...
    [2] => data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSU...
)
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/RRMcJ)